# Missing DLLs in Dependency Walker. Trying to load DLL. Unable to load DLL 'libscvpcli.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, dependency-walker

I have a DLL called libscvpcli.dll, both x64 and x32 versions. When I try to import functions from this dll, I get the error message "Unable to load DLL 'libscvpcli.dll': The specified module could not be found." I have tried changing the target platform on my program from x86 to x64, as well as swapping between the x64 version and the x32 version, but nothing worked.

I tried downloading all Visual Studio Redistributables up to the 2015-2019 one, but that didn't work either.

I used Dependency Walker to check the dependencies of the DLL and it appears I am missing a few.

Here is a picture of what I get when using Dependency Walker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX3tY.png)

Comment: Ignore all of of the MS dlls - dependency walker has not been updated in a while and does not know how to find some of the runtime DLLs.  (1) are any other DLLs missing? (2) What do you mean by _"...import functions from this dll_..."_?  Importing is a compile/link time task and the error you report is a runtime error.

Comment: There is a replacement here for Dependency Walker that fixes a few bugs and false positives: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!
1) After trying the project that "drescherjm" linked, I was able to discover that indeed Dependency Walker showed missing dlls when the dlls where not actually missing. Using the new project, the only dll shown to be missing was "libwinpthread-1.dll". I'm going to try and manually download this and see what happens.

2) I am importing the DLL to C# using the [DLLImport] tag. I am getting this error when I can a basic function from the DLL. I got the class the does the imports with the DLL, so I'm quite sure the code there is correctly using the methods.

Comment: I downloaded the missing DLL and it worked like a charm! Thank you for the help! I'm new to posting questions here so I'm struggling to select the answers as good answers and to close this question lol

Comment: There is probably a duplicate for the dependency walker problem that this question can be closed with.

Comment: Yes, it does. It mentions the new program on github, and users should be able to figure out the issues from there.